# "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding" everytime I wake up my laptop

Tags: 11.04, firefox, sleep

Whenever I wake up my laptop after a few hours or more have past, the laptop takes a minute or more to wake up, making a lot of noise calculating something, and when finally it starts becoming somehow usable, Firefox shows me the message:

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm:282
```

Sometimes it is other scripts.

Obviously it does not happen when I close Firefox before closing the lid, and waking up is much faster. It might be linked to Gmail specifically.

Any idea what is going on and how to stop it from happening?

*Natty/Lenovo Thinkpad R500/ATI*

Comment: happens in Windows, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that at return from sleep, Firefox would see scripts have been running for an unusual long time (because of sleep) and thus proposed to kill them.

Answer (score 1):

I expect the problem is with your [session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29) expiring on the server.

When your client, Firefox tries to initiate communication it will use the expired [session_ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID) / [cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie). In gmails case, the server expires sessions when you log out, or if there has been no communication with the client for a few minutes about 15. Gmail, uses [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to continuously check if the client is connected. It maintains a list of all currently active connections sessions using unique sessionID associated with an account.

When you go into hibernate, you browser looses its connection to the server, and your session will expire on the server. When you try to reconnect, the scripts on your client will try to connect using a sessionID the server does not know exists, as it destroyed that session when it could no longer detect that your client was connected.

Comment: +1 Interesting. So is it something that is inevitable? It does not seem to happen to everybody.